# Rebus: written on many places

Tags: rebus

I have seen this (not the rebus, but what it represents) written on many places. Could you guess what it is and on where I may have seen it?

[image]

Comment: Is there Latin involved?

Comment: No. There is no Latin involved as far as I know :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps

> S(t)ick no bills

as illustrated for instance at
https://www.flickr.com/photos/codein/90245453

Explanation>

> Sick with Tea = Sick with T = **STICK**
>  Forbidden sign = **NO**
>  Bill Pullman, Bill Murray, Bill Hader, Bill Maher, Bill Walton = **BILLS**

Comment: Yep, I believe this is the answer. The first word makes sense if you observe the first image more carefully. (I don't know how to do spoilers, so will refrain from explaining)

Comment: Ah ha! I haven't seen this phrasing. Must be a localisation thing. Like the usage of "tea", though.

Comment: oh my god, I missed the tea. brilliant.

Comment: @question_asker yeah, that single cup of tea made me upvote this question :D

Comment: @Gamow. You nailed it. If you can add a little more explanation, it will be clear for others to understand how you figured it out. :)

Comment: Is this phrase a B.E. thing?

Comment: @Kevin somewhat. Calling them "bills" is more British English than American, where we'd call them "ads" or "promotional posters" (promos) or "flyers" or something. That's a shame because some of these signs say "BILL POSTERS WILL BE PROSECUTED" and sometimes people write underneath, as if in protest, "BILL POSTERS IS INNOCENT!"

Comment: @CRDrost It's not just the 'bills' part but the 'stick no' as well

Answer (score 10):

It could be

> BS

Due to

> "ill" not "bills" - subtract the first from the second and you get BS.

Comment: Oh wow! I didn't expect this...

Answer (score 4):

The only thing that comes to mind is

> post no bills

I just can't find the connection for the first word.

Comment: I'm with you on this.

Comment: @Raystafarian See the comments on Gamow's answer for a hint ;)

Answer (score 1):

I could think of:

> "Sick leaves are not paid"

the explanation is:

> "If sick, No Bills"

Answer (score 1):

It could be:

> **Post** - The image shows a sick spot and "post" is an anagram of "spot"
>  **No**
>  **Bills** - the pictures are of people called Bill.

It would have been seen:

> On the walls of many buildings or on hoardings where the owners don't want flyposters to stick up advertising material.